# How to click on plus button for expand div then all of div don't be clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have a portlet div that has portlet-toggle which is minus/plus icon for expand/collapse, but when I clicked on it, div was selected. What should I do?

portlet:

```
<div class="portlet portlet-count firstTab" id="1">
     <div class="portlet-header">First</div>
     <div class="portlet-content">test-test-test</div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(".portlet")
      .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
      .find(".portlet-header")
        .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
        .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");

    $(".portlet-toggle").click(function () {
        var icon = $(this);
        icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
        icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();  
    });
```

javascript:

```
$('.frame .portlet').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $error;
    if ($this.hasClass('added')) {
        $error = $this.next('.clone-error');
        if (!$error.length) {
            $error = $('<span />', {
                'class': 'clone-error',
                html: '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" style="width: 300px"> This question is already added!</div>'
            }).insertAfter(this);
        }
        $error.stop().show().delay(800).hide(1);
    } else {
        $this.addClass('added').clone().appendTo('#creation .newFrame');
        count++;
    }
});
```

Comment: which plugin are you using? add more details

Comment: What do you mean "div was selected"?

Comment: Please add more details about question. What you need to really achieve?

Comment: are you using `jQuery UI`?

Comment: When div was clicked (clicked on portlet-content), count will be increase. So, when plus/minus button was click, it shouldn't be counted. @RejithRKrishnan yes, I'm using jQuery ui.

Comment: div was clicked @Barmar

Comment: Can you create a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @PloyyPpositive have you tried jquery UI toogle? jqueryui.com/toggle I dont know what you need exactly. But if you are looking for simple toggle effect on plus or minus click, you can use this http://jsfiddle.net/k2k4C/